# Python Request in unicode

Tags: python, unicode, steam-web-api

I am trying to make a program that requests to steam to get a the cheapest price for an item. For this I will be using StatTrak™ P250 | Supernova (Factory New) as an example.

The problem is that when requesting, you will make a url:

```
http://www.steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=SG&currency=13&appid=730&market_hash_name=StatTrak™%20P250%20%7C%20Supernova%20%28Factory%20New%29
```

Afterwards, (I am using the requests module) I do this:

```
url = "http://www.steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=SG&currency=13&appid=730&market_hash_name=StatTrak™%20P250%20%7C%20Supernova%20%28Factory%20New%29"
requests.get(url)
```

However, the server will return an error.

I can't seem to find solutions to replace ™. I have tried `%2122`. In python I tried using `u'\u084a'` but that didn't work too. The problem is that python sends literally `\u084a` in the request. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: You need to properly encode and quote the parameter; see the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use URL encoding. You can't use unicode in urls.

```
>>> import urllib 
>>> f = {'market_hash_name': 'StatTrak™'}
>>> urllib.urlencode(f)
'market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2'
```

Also possible

```
>>> urllib.quote_plus('StatTrak™')
```